# Is it possible to play the YouTubePlayer via STREAM_ALARM

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have an alarm clock app and i want the users to be able to set a youtube video as their alarm. The thing is that the YouTubePlayer is playing via the music stream, which means that if the user is going to sleep while the earphones are plugged to the smartphone, he/she won't be able to hear the alarm. On the MediaPlayer i can set the alarm to use the phone speakers by using this line of code:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, stream_music_volume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Is there a possibility to do the same with the YouTubePlayer or i have to play it via the music stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You can not change YoutubePlayer's stream type.
You are not allowed to play youtube videos in the background.
That being said you should not use a online resource as an alarm, a network connection might not be available. You should instead download the media file and use a mediaplayer (which can handle online resources) and adjust the stream type via `setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)`. You can adjust the media player's volume by using `adjustVolume` or AudioManager's `setStreamVolume`, but you might have to get the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission. Note that you should also get the `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` permission to override the Do Not Dirturb feature if you were to use YoutubePlayer in the background as a media stream.

Comment: I am not playing the youtube video on the background. I play it on the UI thread. And if i can't load the video i play the default ringtone of the device, so i don't think that there should be any problem with that. And just like i wrote on the question, i know how to adjust the media player but in order to play a video on the media player i need the YouTube video rtsp link, which i am able to get but not so sure it is OK with the YouTube policy.  Since i got no solution so far i guess that your answer is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about YouTubePlayer API but you could you [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/). The API allows you to set the stream type (see [issue #755](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/755)) and is able to play youtube videos. There is a [demo project](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demo) with [yt videos](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demo/src/main/assets/media.exolist.json#L3).

Comment: In order to use the ExpoPlayer i need to get the youtube video rtsp link, which i am not sure is legal in the youtube policy.

Comment: I don't know. At least they provide YT links as sample.

Answer (score 0):

yes, on receive broadcast of alarm, you can create a little window using window manager and code to play youtube video in it.

Comment: I know how to play a youtube video.But how do i play the video on the YouTubePlayer via the alarm stream?